# Matlab - symsum with itegral

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to calculate the following:

[image: equation]

I am using the following code:

```
clear all;
close all
clc;
SNR0dB = 40;       
SNR0 = 10 ^ (SNR0dB / 10);
LaserIntensity = 1877;    
EffNoisePower = 4;     
tmp_sigma = 20;
m=1;
rho=0.5;
H=1;
C = sqrt(SNR0*EffNoisePower) / LaserIntensity;
Zn_1  = inf;
Zn    = C / 0.204;
syms k x
S1 = symsum(( ((rho*m)/(H^2*(1-rho^2)))^(m+2*k-1) ) * (1/(factorial(k)*gamma(m+k))) * integral(@(r1) r1.^(2*m+2*k+1).*exp((-r1.^2.*m)/(H^2*(1-rho^2))),Zn,Zn_1), k, 0, 10)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511) Input function
>   must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.
>
> Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
>                   finalInputChecks(x,fx);
>
> Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
>                   [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
>
> Error in integralCalc (line 83)
>                   [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);
>
> Error in integral (line 88) Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
>
> Error in SumOverIntegral (line 21) S1 = symsum((
>       ((rho*m)/(H^2*(1-rho^2)))^(m+2*k-1) ) * (1/(factorial(k)*gamma(m+k)))
>       * integral(@(r1) r1.^(2*m+2*k+1).*exp((-r1.^2.*m)/(H^2*(1-rho^2))),Zn,Zn_1), k, 0, 10)

Can someone please help with how to overcome the error of sending symbol to the integral function?

Comment: For symbolic expressions, use `int` from the symbolic toolbox, not integral.

Comment: A very typical mistake in Matlab. Mixing apples and oranges. Can't use syms with numerical functions.